# Symfony (doctrine) database interact with Java/C/C++ server

Tags: java, php, mysql, doctrine

I used `Symphony3` to set up my website and doctrine to connect my MySQL database.

I have my entities written in php and I use `doctrine:schema:update` to update my database.

I would like to create a socket server (live communication) in another language (Java, C / C ++ ...) which has access to my database. I would like this access to be automated by a framework (as a doctrine).

Is it possible ? I will have to set up 2 classes (in each languages) for 1 element in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would make my symfony app as a REST API and consume it from any rest client in other languages.

To easily make a Restful API from your Symfony entities you can use FOSRestBundle: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html